# Redir to HTTPS in IIS 8.0 going weird if HTTP://

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have an ASP.net website running under IIS 8.0. The base URL is `https://www.example.com`. (Certificate is correctly installed for www.example.com and works fine)

The bindings for this website are

- www.example.com port 80
- www.example.com port 443
- example.com port 80

The first rewrite rule in web.config is

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The URL `https://www.example.com` works perfectly.
The URL `http://www.example.com` redirects correctly.
The URL `example.com` redirects correctly.

My problem is : if I try `http://example.com`, I get a blank page (just containing 
`<html><body></body></html>`)

Thanks in advance for help.

Regards,

Guy

Comment: DO you have another rewrite rules in your web.config? Because i checked your rule and it's working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the DNS : 2 A records for example.com. One of them was pointing to a disabled previous hosting.